# Pointer points to uninitialized variable

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, behavior

In the following program, `ptr` points to **uninitialized** variable `x`. Before printing `ptr`, I have assigned `10` to `ptr` and print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int x;

    ptr = &x;
    *ptr = 10;

    printf(" x = %d\n", x);
    printf(" *ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
}
```

Both `ptr` and `x` print the correct value. But, I have doubt, **Is it defined behavior?**

Comment: Please read about it. Why do you think it would be defined or undefined? Where is your research effort? What did you find which you did not understand? Adding those makes it a good question, no offense.

Comment: You only invoke potentially poorly-defined behavior when you _access the value_ of a variable that has not been initialized.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with "Before dereferenced `ptr`, i have assigned `10` to `ptr` and dereferenced it." ? Assigning `10`to `*ptr`(not `ptr`is dereferencing. You dereference it before you dereference it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is. You assign a valid value to `ptr` and then use indirection to assign a valid value to `x`.

The address of a variable like `x` and its value are separate things. After storage is allocated, taking the address is always well defined, regardless of the value in the variable.

Comment: (though the compiler may still optimize these *as if*, as the pointer is never passed around anywhere)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Yeah, it certainly may. The behavior of the code still remains will defined either way, however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , because when you declare x the placeholder / memory will become available
for you .

`ptr = &x;
*ptr = 10;`

code effectively means

`x =10`

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding it is defined behaviour, as it it not necessary to have memory initialized before writing to it.